# How can i open web page in android activity?

Tags: android, xml, webview

[Image with xml file which has three buttons while clicking upon button it should show appropriate web page in webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyL2S.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code. You can configure it however you want:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    googleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    googleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
      }

    });
}
}
```

Note that you need INTERNET permission for that in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thanks.. its working properly :)

Comment: @kuldeep zala You are welcome. Verify the answer so that others know it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add in your java code in onClickListener of button :

```
webview.loadUrl("http://google.fr/");
```

See Android documentation : [Webview Android Developper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)